# Failed to choose DirectX12 adapter

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose, directx-12

I'm using the Intellij IDE for Kotlin. I was trying the compose UI tutorial and when I ran a basic program I get this message 'Failed to choose DirectX12 Adapter. The window opens and appears to be working. What do I need to do to choose the adapter?

```
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }

    MaterialTheme {
        Button(onClick = {
            text = "Hello, Desktop!"
        }) {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Failed Message]

[image: Picture of DirectX Diagnostic tool]

I used the dxdiag command and it appears DirectX 12 is installed.

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 2/9/2023, 22:18:43
         Machine name: DESKTOP-JQ7CR2F
           Machine Id: {B31A9997-C49B-4C8D-84B7-67A3C21C6D33}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit (10.0, Build 19044) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
         System Model: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
                 BIOS: BIOS Date: 07/27/15 17:53:10 Ver: 04.06.05 (type: BIOS)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8128MB RAM
            Page File: 14425MB used, 8359MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\Windows
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Not Available
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
DirectX Database Version: 1.0.8
DxDiag Version: 10.00.19041.2075 64bit Unicode

---

### DxDiag Notes

```
  Display Tab 1: No problems found.
  Display Tab 2: No problems found.
    Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
    Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
    Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
    Sound Tab 4: No problems found.
      Input Tab: No problems found.
```

---

### DirectX Debug Levels

Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---

### Display Devices

```
       Card name: NVIDIA GeForce 210 
    Manufacturer: NVIDIA
       Chip type: GeForce 210
        DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
     Device Type: Full Device (POST)
      Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0A65&SUBSYS_082E196E&REV_A2
   Device Status: 0180200A
```